# See through model in BGE

Tags: modeling, game-engine, transparency

I am making a sort of Sonic Game, and I have a rigged sonic model. It looks fine in edit, object, and pose mode
 [image]

but when I try to test it, it looks like this.

[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: It is hard to see, but the  eyes are supposed to be curved on top, but they are not. Also, you are not supposed to be able to see the part of the shoe that is underneath the sock, but you can see that too. I will get better screenshots, one second.

Comment: It is supposed to look like this

Comment: Hmm, its not letting me add the screenshot?

Comment: Make sure the normals are pointing in the right direction. And if that's not the case check the the material settings that no transparency is enabled.

Comment: Transparency was checked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Transparency was enabled on the model. It was on the material that had the texture for the whole model. Since it was one big texture, the whole thing was transparent. It was the tab Transparency under the shadow options for the material.
[image]